# How to set static period for XAxis in ComposedChart (material-ui)

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I tried to configurate my ComposedChar, but XAxis is always dynamic.

for XAxis I have data in minutes, from 0-60.

Is it possible to set is as 0, 10, 20...60.

Maybe somebody know, please help.

Thanks in advance.

My code is bellow:

```html
<ComposedChart
          width={1240}
          height={600}
          data={validDate}
          margin={{ top: 70, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 20 }}>
          <XAxis dataKey='name' />
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5' />
          <Bar dataKey='time' barSize={30} fill='#413ea0' />
          <Line type='monotone' dataKey='time' stroke='#ff7300' />
</ComposedChart>
```

Picture for better understanding [image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This: `<XAxis tickCount={7} domain={[0, 60]}/>`